# Why tensorflow's FLOPs is 2 times Caffe's macc?

Tags: tensorflow, caffe, flops

I'm trying to rewrite a model from caffe to tensorflow. To make sure I did not make mistake, I count the macc and Flops and then I find this interesting thing:

For example, when input a image 112x112x3, and conv2d it with 32 3x3 kernel, stride=1, the macc in Caffe is 2.71M, while the FLOPs computed in tensorflow is 5. 42M.

I wonder why this 2x difference happen?

Answer (score 5):

One MACC contains one multiplication and one addition. 
One multiplication or one addition can be seen as one FLOP. 
So one MACC has two FLOPS.

Comment: I know I'm late to the game, but I'm looking for a cite worthy source for this statement. Can you please provide me with some? I only find some post in forums to this topic.

Answer (score 1):

i am not expert in this but FLOPS mean every floating point operation and not just multiplies or accumulates. There would be more FLOPS performed than MACS performed.

also i have read somewhere that
If the MACs are for floating point performance and the loop overheads
and memory bandwidths are identical for the two measurements,
then usually 1 floating-point Multiply-Accumulate is considered
equivalent to 2 FLOPs. One for the multipy and Second for addition in accumulator.